# SQL query to calculate running group counts on time-phased data

Tags: sql

I have some data, like this:

```
BUG  DATE                   STATUS
---- ---------------------- --------
9012 18/03/2008 9:08:44 AM  OPEN
9012 18/03/2008 9:10:03 AM  OPEN
9012 28/03/2008 4:55:03 PM  RESOLVED
9012 28/03/2008 5:25:00 PM  CLOSED
9013 18/03/2008 9:12:59 AM  OPEN
9013 18/03/2008 9:15:06 AM  RESOLVED
9013 18/03/2008 9:16:44 AM  CLOSED
9014 18/03/2008 9:17:54 AM  OPEN
9014 18/03/2008 9:18:31 AM  RESOLVED
9014 18/03/2008 9:19:30 AM  CLOSED
9015 18/03/2008 9:22:40 AM  OPEN
9015 18/03/2008 9:23:03 AM  RESOLVED
9015 19/03/2008 12:27:08 PM CLOSED
9016 18/03/2008 9:24:20 AM  OPEN
9016 18/03/2008 9:24:35 AM  RESOLVED
9016 19/03/2008 12:28:14 PM CLOSED
9017 18/03/2008 9:25:47 AM  OPEN
9017 18/03/2008 9:26:02 AM  RESOLVED
9017 19/03/2008 12:30:30 PM CLOSED
```

Which I would like to transform into something like this:

```
DATE                       OPEN RESOLVED   CLOSED
---------------------- -------- -------- --------
18/03/2008 9:08:44 AM         1        0        0
18/03/2008 9:12:59 AM         2        0        0
18/03/2008 9:15:06 AM         1        1        0
18/03/2008 9:16:44 AM         1        0        1
18/03/2008 9:17:54 AM         2        0        1
18/03/2008 9:18:31 AM         1        1        0
18/03/2008 9:19:30 AM         1        0        2
18/03/2008 9:22:40 AM         2        0        2
18/03/2008 9:23:03 AM         1        1        2
18/03/2008 9:24:20 AM         2        1        2
18/03/2008 9:24:35 AM         1        2        2
18/03/2008 9:25:47 AM         2        2        2
18/03/2008 9:26:02 AM         1        3        2
19/03/2008 12:27:08 PM        1        2        3
19/03/2008 12:28:14 PM        1        1        4
19/03/2008 12:30:30 PM        1        0        5
28/03/2008 4:55:03 PM         0        1        5
28/03/2008 5:25:00 PM         0        0        6
```

i.e. keeping running counts of bugs with each status.

This is easy enough to code up using cursors, but I'm wondering if any of you SQL gurus out there can help with a query to achieve this?

Ideally for `mysql`, but I'm curious to see anything that will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
With T as
(
Select B.BugDate As MainDate, C.BugID, C.BugDate ,C.Status,row_number() over(partition by B.BugDate,C.BugID order by C.BugDate Desc) As RowNum From Bug B Cross Join Bug C where B.BugDate >=  C.BugDate Group By B.BugDate,C.BugID,C.BugDate, C.Status 
) 

Select T.MainDate ,SUM(CASE WHEN T.Status = 'OPEN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As SUM_OPEN,SUM(CASE WHEN T.Status = 'RESOLVED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As SUM_RESOLVED
,SUM(CASE WHEN T.Status = 'CLOSED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As SUM_CLOSED
From T
where T.RowNum = 1
Group By T.MainDate
Order By T.MainDate
```

Comment: This is the most succinct demonstration of a working result.  After running it against a table with only 3000 rows, It has convinced me that writing the code is a better way :)

Answer (score 1):

My spontaneous way to do that would not be in the SQL, since it'd require some looping to know the state of each category given the time of the next row. Instead, I'd fetch the original data and loop it through, modifying the amount of each category based on the STATUS-field of each row, and then outputting. If you'd like an example in, say, php, I could give you one.

Another way would be to cache this data in a separate table, and updating it whenever there's a new action. This way you can fetch it faster.

Comment: That was pretty much my thoughts too.  I don't really need help with the code, but I'm not an SQL expert and I thought I might learn something by asking.  Nitin's answer seems both freakishly complicated and interesting.

Comment: I agree that this is one of those problems that do not have a very good all SQL solution. You can do a subquery in on column which sums the counts of all previous records, but then your open gets decremented any time a case is resolved, and your resolved gets decremented any time one is closed. 
A pure SQL implementation would get dog slow as your data grew larger.

Answer (score 1):

As you had said, you expect answer in any SQL implementation, so i am providing an answer for SQL Server 2005 and above, as i am using Windows function (Row_Number) and CROSS APPLY features.

The Idea is to get the last status of a bug for a give time.

Solution:

```
Select  BugDate,
        SUM(Case When RowNum = 1 AND Status = 'OPEN' Then 1 Else 0 End) As Opened,
        SUM(Case When RowNum = 1 AND Status = 'RESOLVED' Then 1 Else 0 End) As Resolved,
        SUM(Case When RowNum = 1 AND Status = 'CLOSED' Then 1 Else 0 End) As Closed
FROM
(
    Select B1.BugDate,T2.BugId,T2.RowNum,T2.[Status]
    from Bug B1
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT  T1.BugDate,T1.BugId, B.[Status],
                ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition by B1.BugDate, T1.BugId Order By Case when B.[Status] IS NULL THEN 1000 ELSE 1 END,T1.BugDate Desc) AS RowNum
        FROM
        (
            Select BugDate,BugId
            FROM
            (
                Select Distinct BugDate 
                from Bug
            ) D
            CROSS JOIN
            (
                Select Distinct BugId
                FROm Bug
            ) AS I
        )T1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN BUG B ON T1.BugDate = B.BugDate and T1.BugId = B.BugId
        WHERE  T1.BugDate <= B1.BugDate --AND T1.BugId = B1.BugId
    ) T2
)T1
GROUP BY BugDate 
Order By BugDate
```

I created a same dataset as you have provided in sample question and the results i got are:

```
Date                   Op   Re  Cl
```

---

```
2008-03-18 09:08:44.000 1   0   0
2008-03-18 09:10:03.000 1   0   0
2008-03-18 09:12:59.000 2   0   0
2008-03-18 09:15:06.000 1   1   0
2008-03-18 09:16:44.000 1   0   1
2008-03-18 09:17:54.000 2   0   1
2008-03-18 09:18:31.000 1   1   1
2008-03-18 09:19:30.000 1   0   2
2008-03-18 09:22:40.000 2   0   2
2008-03-18 09:23:03.000 1   1   2
2008-03-18 09:24:20.000 2   1   2
2008-03-18 09:24:35.000 1   2   2
2008-03-18 09:25:47.000 2   2   2
2008-03-18 09:26:02.000 1   3   2
2008-03-19 12:27:08.000 1   2   3
2008-03-19 12:28:14.000 1   1   4
2008-03-19 12:30:30.000 1   0   5
2008-03-28 16:55:03.000 0   1   5
2008-03-28 17:25:00.000 0   0   6
```

Note: You are missing line 2 in your result set and also row for date 18/03/2008 9:18:31 AM is also not correct in your result.

Comment: OK, that seems pretty awesome.  I'll have to wait until tomorrow to try it out (no SQL server 2005 here), but thanks for looking at the problem.

Comment: This might not be optimized for a very large data, i worked on this solution so to learn. In my opinion, you should have another table which will store the results and you can update this table whenever you have any status change or any new bug opened. if this is a report and user often uses it daily and its OK to show the data with some lag, then u should schedule a job which will calculate the data for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I've accepted Vipin's answer as it is a bit more succinct, however, this works for me too.  Thanks for the lesson in cross joins.  See comment on accepted answer for details on performance.

Answer (score 0):

Sub queries will work, but is it only three statuses that you have? and are they hardcoded or do they vary

EDIT

```
select <TableName>.DATE, (SELECT BUGS FROM CountTable WHERE DATE = <TableName>.DATE AND Status = 'OPEN') as 'OPEN'
        , (SELECT BUGS FROM CountTable WHERE DATE = <TableName>.DATE ANDStatus = 'CLOSED') as 'CLOSED'
        , (SELECT BUGS FROM CountTable WHERE DATE = <TableName>.DATE ANDStatus = 'RESOLVED') as 'RESOLVED'
FROM
<TableName>,
    (   SELECT DATE, STATUS, COUNT(BUG) as BUGS 
    FROM <TableName>
    GROUP BY DATE,STATUS) as CountTable
WHERE CountTable.DATE = <TableName>.DATE
```

Alternatively, for a simpler solution

```
SELECT DATE, (SELECT count(BUGS) FROM <TableName> bugs2 WHERE Status = 'OPEN' AND bugs.DATE = bugs2.DATE) as 'OPEN'
        , (SELECT count(BUGS) FROM <TableName> bugs2 WHERE Status = 'CLOSED' AND bugs.DATE = bugs2.DATE) as 'CLOSED'
        , (SELECT count(BUGS) FROM <TableName> bugs2 WHERE Status = 'RESOLVED' AND bugs.DATE = bugs2.DATE) as 'RESOLVED'
FROM <TableName> bugs
group by DATE
```

Comment: Just the OPEN, RESOLVED and CLOSED statuses. [edit] And they are hardcoded.

Comment: See post for solution. The idea is to create a table (called CountTable) where the data is grouped by date and status. Then we do 3 sub-selects in the main select clause. One for each status, and we join the initial table to the constructed table by date. Also need to add date join to the subqueries... will rectify that

Comment: Is it giving you running totals, i am afraid, for instance see record 3 in output, "18/03/2008 9:15:06 AM         1        1        0", but at input we have only this row "9013 18/03/2008 9:15:06 AM  RESOLVED" for 18/03.2008 9:15:06. You will get 1 in resolved, but how will u get 1 in Open.

Comment: This makes a crosstab on `date` x `status` for `count(bugs)` over the status updates, which is not quite what I wanted to do --- I was really after a running sum.